# Getting double notification popup for single event on ios when sending notification using FCM

Tags: react-native, react-native-firebase

**Issue Description::**

I am working on react native application and using react native firebase messaging service for push notification. I am having a problem on IOS platform. I am getting double notification popups for single event.

Steps I am following to generate the case::

1. After app installation if I am login and sending notification through FCM I just received a single popup. After this I logged out and login again, now this time I got double popups for single notification. In this case I am not clearing an app from background.
2. If after every logout I am clearing an app from background I just received a single popup for single event.
3. When I am logged out from the application, and forcefully sending notification from FCM, I am getting double popup on app initialization screen(login screen).

I am generating a new device token when user login and saving this token inside local storage, we are clearing local storage data on logout.

**Code::**

```
async mountDashboard() {
    const enabled = await firebase.messaging().hasPermission();
    if (enabled) {
        const fcmToken = await firebase.messaging().getToken();
        await AsyncStorage.setItem(LocalStorageKeys.DEVICE_TOKEN, fcmToken);
        if (fcmToken) {
            //--- here we are saving our token and sendind data to API
        }
    }

    // in Foreground
    this.notificationListener = firebase.notifications().onNotification((notification) => {
        new RegisterLocalNotification(notification);
    });

    // App in Foreground and background
    let notificationHandler = new NotificationsHandler();
    this.notificationOpenedListener = firebase.notifications().onNotificationOpened((notificationOpen) => {
        notificationHandler.handleNotification(notificationOpen.notification);
    });

    // app close notification handler
    AppCloseNotificationHandler.getInstance().handleNotification();

}

componentDidMount() {
    this.mountDashboard();
}
```

**Environment::**

**Binaries:**

- Node: 10.15.0 - /usr/local/opt/node@10/bin/node
- Yarn: 1.10.1 -/usr/local/bin/yarn
- npm: 6.4.1 - /usr/local/opt/node@10/bin/npm
- Watchman: 4.9.0 - /usr/local/bin/watchman
- List item

**npm Packages:**

- react: ^16.8.4 => 16.8.4
- react-native: ^0.58.6 => 0.58.6

**npm Global Packages:**

- react-native-cli: 2.0.1
- react-native-firebase: 5.2.3

Comment: Are you calling your listener during onUnmount as the doc says ?

Comment: I am just calling my function inside componentDidmount(), can you mention the link.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to unsubscribe from your listener when the component will unmount. If you don't do that you are subscribing two listeners.

```
componentWillUnmount() {
    this.notificationListener(); // it's unsubscribing your listener
}
```

Comment: Why you are not unmounting the this.notificationOpenedListener.

Comment: I can't test it and I don't know if it will have side effect. You said you need it when your app is in background mode, so perhaps it will not catch notification in some case. I thinks you forget to add `getInitialNotification`, if you use this function you can call `notificationOpenedListener` in the unmount safely.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to send this payload via backend, I am using firebase admin SDK.
This will disable Notification By OS and trigger the local notification. I am using this package for local notification https://github.com/zo0r/react-native-push-notification

```
async function sendPushNotification(message) {

try {
    await admin.messaging().sendToDevice(
        ['dCk27uEySymSdP_vA1C_QI:APA91bEZNyipZDjTLq0jrGnD0qcpKH2y3oTYg3GMgT0pSENNlJEiymOYXvxvnqTFtQaidDLt5KUgp4oDZsfLsQvfiVkL7m1bpMjekHsm-7x1ZDju4TYUMUZeUgYb0CyPwMhdr9RyzA1v'],
        {
            data: {
                owner: 'a',
                user: 'a',
            },
        },
        {
            // Required for background/quit data-only messages on iOS
            contentAvailable: true,
            // Required for background/quit data-only messages on Android
            priority: 'high',
        },
    );

    console.log('A');

}catch(e) {
    console.log('Gagal mengirim pesan');
}

}
```

And this my code inside App.js that listen to the notification

*RNFirebase.onMessage(RNFirebaseOnMessageHandler);
RNFirebase.setBackgroundMessageHandler(RNFirebaseOnMessageHandler);*

And inside the handler, I use this

```
PushNotification.createChannel(
    {
      channelId: CHANNEL_ID,
      channelName: CHANNEL_NAME,
      channelDescription: CHANNEL_DESCRIPTION,
      soundName: CHANNEL_SOUND,
      importance: CHANNEL_IMPORTANCE,
      vibrate: CHANNEL_VIBRATE,
    },
    (created) => console.log(`createChannel returned '${created}'`), // (optional) callback returns whether the channel was created, false means it already existed.
  );
  PushNotification.localNotification({
    channelId: CHANNEL_ID,
    // @todo get ticker value from data payload
    ticker: 'CreateOrderLandingScreen',
    showWhen: true,
    autoCancel: true,
    largeIcon: CHANNEL_LARGE_ICON,
    smallIcon: CHANNEL_SMALL_ICON,
    bigText: 'aaaaa',
    subText: CHANNEL_SUB_TEXT,
    color: Colors.RED,
    vibrate: true,
    vibration: 300,
    priority: 'high',
    visibility: 'private',
    invokeApp: true,
    alertAction: 'view',
    id: 0,
    title:'aa',
    message: 'aaaa',
    userInfo: {},
    playSound: false,
    soundName: 'default',
  });
```